# AngularJS Testing a Service with $http and $q

Tags: service, angularjs, jasmine, promise, karma-runner

I'm new to AngularJS and to JS testing in general and I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around how to go about testing this rather simple service. I've tried using $httpBackend with 'when' and 'expect' GET in variations configurations, to no avail. The test should verify that 1) data is returned via the deferred.resolve and 2) no data is returned via the deferred.reject. If someone could point me in the right direction i'd be quite grateful. Thanks!

btw: I'm using Jasmine + Testacular

```
.service('myService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getMyData: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get('/foo/bar.do').success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(){
                deferred.reject();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: httpBackend should do it.  Can you post some test code that didn't work?

Comment: Are you using $httpBackend.flush()?

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of the same problem testing a service with $http and $q.
Here is one of my test which passes:

```
it('should issue a GET request to /foo/bar.do', inject(function ($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.when('GET', '/foo/bar.do').respond('success');
  var finalResult = '';

  var result = myService.getMyData();

  result.then(function(data) {
    finalResult = data;
  }, function() {
    console.log('error');
  });

  $httpBackend.flush();

  expect(finalResult).toBe('success');
}));
```